# Get column data from HBase via JRuby script

Tags: hadoop, hbase, jruby

I can get value for certain column in `HBase` table via `hbase shell`:

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'some_table', {STARTROW => '7af02800f4c6478cde0f55e8bce34f4a2efa48f2', LIMIT => 1, COLUMNS => ['foo:bar']}
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
 7af02800f4c6478cde0f55e8bce34f4a2efa48f2   column=foo:bar, timestamp=0, value=http://someurl.com/some/path
1 row(s) in 0.4430 seconds
```

I would like to reproduce the same with `jruby` script. The following is my approach.

```
include Java
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get

tableName = 'some_table'
conf = HBaseConfiguration.create
ht = HTable.new(conf, tableName)
key = '7af02800f4c6478cde0f55e8bce34f4a2efa48f2'
my_get = Get.new(key.to_java_bytes)
result = ht.get(my_get)

# And what to do now?
```

What is the correct way to obtain column value from `HBase` table via `JRuby`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include Java
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

tableName = 'some_table'
conf = HBaseConfiguration.create
ht = HTable.new(conf, tableName)
key = '7af02800f4c6478cde0f55e8bce34f4a2efa48f2'
my_get = Get.new(key.to_java_bytes)
result = ht.get(my_get)

# This
puts Bytes.toStringBinary(result.getValue('foo'.to_java_bytes, 'bar'.to_java_bytes))
```